How to customize the space between specific lines on a QTextDocument?
I'm trying to set a custom spacing between just the first line and the second and all other lines should have the same line spacing.
image
      QTextEdit*   textEdit = new QTextEdit;
      QTextDocument* doc = new QTextDocument;
      QString html = R"(
<p><span style="line-height: 10px;"><font style="font-size: 11px; color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255);"> world — 05/04/2024 3:15 PM </font></span></p>
<br>green
<br>blue
)";

        doc->setHtml(html);

I have tried line-height but independent of the value i insert the space between the lines continue the same.

If you have one <p> per line you could just set the margin-bottom property of the first <p> and be done with it, I think.

@Botje i tried it, same thing, no difference in the space between the lines.

I can't spot an issue in your code at first glance so I did it in the designer (simple widget with just 1 text edit) in which I pasted your html string and it works: I get a bigger space between the 1st and 2nd lines, 2nd and 3rd lines are not spaced. I suggest you do that too, compile the resulting uic and see what it does differently from you.

I don't know how to implement what you want by html.
If you can accept codes, I submit this answer.
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QTextDocument>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    int SpecialSpace = 30;
    QTextEdit* t = new QTextEdit();
    QTextDocument* d = new QTextDocument(t);
    QTextCursor tc(d);
    t->setDocument(d);

    QTextBlockFormat specialBf = tc.blockFormat();
    specialBf.setLineHeight(SpecialSpace, QTextBlockFormat::LineHeightTypes::FixedHeight);
    tc.setBlockFormat(specialBf);
    QTextCharFormat specialCf;
    specialCf.setForeground(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255));
    tc.insertText("SpecialBf1  -world — 05/04/2024 3:15 PM", specialCf);
    QTextCharFormat normalCf;
    tc.insertBlock(specialBf);
    tc.insertText("NormalBf", normalCf);
    QTextBlockFormat normalBf;
    tc.insertBlock(normalBf);
    tc.insertText("NormalBf");

    w.setCentralWidget(t);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

This is a demonstration for coming true what you want.
If you want to come true this situation in any case, you should override keyPressEvent and handle line heights of the first line and second line.
If you can use customLayout, it is very easy to do and omit the redundancy.

